# Multiple SQL fetch and print html-code if two tables is true

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to achieve a PHP, SQL and HTML solution. This is probably commonly done.

I have coded a project overview system from scratch. The state right now is that I have a SQL table for USERS and another table for PROJECTS. It works great to sign in with each user and also to list all projects for all the users.

But to be able to track which users that are connected to each project I created a third SQL table which is called PROJECTMEMBERS. It contains the rows USERS_ID and PROJECTS_ID which are supposed to hold the ID from the user and the project to be able to track the projectmembers. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but found it in another thread and thought it made sense. But now..

I have issues to figure out how to access different SQL tables in the same `mysqli_fetch()` query. How is this possibly done to present the USER IMAGE in each project? The current fetch is used to present all the projects but I still want to show all projects, but with an image of the active users on the project on each.

I hope I was clear enough for anyone to understand. Looking forward to any help out there.

SQL STRUCTURE EXAMPLE:

```
tbl_USERS                                    tbl_PROJECTS

| id | username | USER_IMG | etc |            | id | PROJECTNAME | DATE | etc | 
----------------------------------            ----------------------------------
|  1 | XXXX     | XXXXXXXX |  1  |            |  1 | AAAA        | AAAA |  1  |
|  2 | YYYY     | YYYYYYYY |  2  |            |  2 | BBBB        | BBBB |  3  |
|  3 | ZZZZ     | ZZZZZZZZ |  1  |            |  3 | CCCC        | CCCC |  4  |

tbl_PROJECTMEMBERS 

| USERS_ID | PROJECTS_ID |         
-------------------------       
|  1       | 1           |           
|  1       | 5           |          
|  2       | 1           |
```

How it should be presented where USER_IMG is fetched from the users table:

```
--------------------------------   --------------------------------  
|  PROJECTNAME                 |   |  PROJECTNAME                 |
|  DATE                        |   |  DATE                        |
|                              |   |                              |
|                              |   |                              |
| USER_IMG, USER_IMG           |   |  USER_IMG, USER_IMG          |
--------------------------------   --------------------------------

--------------------------------
|  PROJECTNAME                 |
|  DATE                        |
|                              |
|                              |
| USER_IMG                     |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have 3 table users and projects and user_projects and you are fetching only projects from projects table then you can add join the first query where you fetch the projects it could some like this

SELECT p.*,user.* FROM projects as p 
INNER JOIN user_projects as up
    ON up.project_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN users 
    ON users.id = up.user_id

Above I have used multijoin where project table connected with user_project and user_project conned with users table and in the select query we have fetch project and users table.

In above query you might get query if same attribute get repate into the both table like (ambiguity)  so you can just skip the error just by alise it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user.id AS 'User ID', project.id as 'Project ID', project.name as 'Project Name' from user tbl_USERS , project tbl_PROJECTS, userprojects tbl_PROJECTMEMBERS  where user.id = userprojects.USERS_ID AND project.id = userprojects.PROJECT_ID
```

This would be your mysql query, it would fetch the user id as User ID, project Id as Project ID, and project name as Project Name.

You can access those variables in plain php and output anyway you like.

Comment: You dont need to run a check if your project id and user id is a match, because the joins of MYsql would do that for you.

If you'd like to create a little bit more queries involving multiple tables. You should really read about joins in SQL, hope i helped!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!

I will read more about joins.
I updated the thread with more detailed information. Is it still the right way to go with joins since I always want to list all the projects but in each project post I want to show the users that are working on the specific project.

Comment: This is an M to M relationship.

Multiple Projects can have Multiple Users.

Multiple Users can work on Multiple Projects.

You want to show a single project, and all of its users?

Iterating through all projects like that.

Comment: I want to list all the projects with the active users that match with the ID of the user and the PROJECT from tbl_PROJECTMEMBERS listed on each of the projects as a Image of the user from the USERS table. Then I want the user to be able to click on any of the projects to get more details and then only show the users on the specific project.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM USERS a INNER JOIN PROJECTS b on a.userID = b.userID 
          RIGHT JOIN USER_PROJECTS c ON a.userID = c.userID 
          WHERE a.userID = $variable";
$result = $db->Execute($query)
foreach($result as $data){
    if($data['userID'] == $data['projectID']){
        //do stuff here 
    }
}
```